# Somar valores de um campo de uma tabela

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela onde armazeno os valores do frete, porém quando o carrinho é atualizado com o valor do frete, esse valor também é atualizado na tabela. Porém se o pedido #1111 tiver 3 produtos no carrinho, ele vai incluir nessa tabela os valores do frete atualizado. Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de somar os valores do Frete, mas com o cuidado de não somar 02 vezes o frete do mesmo pedido, que no caso é 16.10. Tentei essa query, mas não funcionou:

```
SELECT SUM(ValorFrete) AS ValorTFrete FROM loja_carrinho WHERE StatusCompras = 'aguardando' GROUP BY ValorFrete
```

Ele me retorna apenas um primeiro valor e não soma os valores.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao agrupar por Pedido, retorna dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer a soma geral de todos os pedidos? mas, que não repita pelo numpedido?

Comment: Isso. Quero somar o valor do frete, mas não repetindo caso seja do mesmo NumPedido, ou seja, na primeira imagem, gostaria de somar 16.10 + 17.20 e não 16.10 + 16.10 + 17.20

Comment: Testa a SQL que eu mudei agora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro deve selecionar os itens que se repetem, e depois somar o valor do frete, ***exemplo***:

```
SELECT SUM(ValorTFrete) FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT NumPedido, ValorTFrete           
    FROM loja_carrinho 
    WHERE StatusCompras = 'aguardando'
) AS t
```

Comment: Olá Virgílio. Também tentei isso, porém ele me retorna da forma como a imagem que editei agora no post. Só o primeiro valor 56.20

Comment: @Fox.11 vou arrumar a SQL

Comment: @Fox.11 acho que é com distinct! então.

Comment: Funcionou!! Muito obrigado Virgílio.